# How to Convert Color Type to Gradient Type in NavigationBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, gradient, material3

I'm building `NavigationBar` using `Material Design 3` which is basically a new `bottom navigation bar`. On `NavigationBar` there is a widget called `NavigationBarTheme` where i can put `indicator` color. Now the problem is `indicator` color is a `Color` Type and i want to show this in a `Gradient Color` Type. I checked many hours in the internet but could not find the solution to convert `Color` Type to `Gradient Color` Type. Below is the sample code

```
NavigationBarTheme(
      data: NavigationBarThemeData(
          indicatorColor: const Color(0xFF5fc9b9), // Here want to show in gradient color
          indicatorShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          labelTextStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
              GoogleFonts.almarai(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600))),
      child: NavigationBar(
        selectedIndex: widget.index,
        destinations: [
          NavigationDestination(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.meeting_room_outlined),
              selectedIcon: const Icon(
                Icons.meeting_room_rounded,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              label: listOfMeetings),
          NavigationDestination(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.account_balance_outlined),
              selectedIcon: const Icon(
                Icons.account_balance_rounded,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              label: financialData),
        ],
      ),
    );
```